# How to know what is color of TextInputLayout error in Android?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am using several Textinputlayouts in my app. How may I know  what is color lf its error?
[image]

Comment: what color? There are a lot of colors, text, stroke, hint, background.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default error color is based on the **`colorError`** attribute.
The [current value](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.2.1/lib/java/com/google/android/material/color/res/values/colors.xml#L33) in a light theme is:

```
<color name="design_default_color_error">#B00020</color>
```

If you want to use it in another attribute you can copy this value or you can use **`?attr/colorError`**. Example:

```
<item name="strokeColor">?attr/colorError</item>
```

If you want to get programmatically this value you can use:

```
MaterialColors.getColor(fab, R.attr.colorError)
```

Comment: Thanks. Really I don't want to change any color. I want to have error color to use it in another place.

Answer (score 0):

The default color for layout error is red. You can change it if you want. You just need to add lines in style.xml

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutError" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">your color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Use below tag in your TextInputLayout tag

```
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutError">
```

Comment: It is **not** totally correct. The color is based on the `colorError` attribute and not necessary it is red. The best way to change the errorTextColor is using the `errorTextColor` attribute in the layout/style and in any case in this way you are not changing the hint color and the stroke color.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but generally it is red and we can not get the exact color code which TextInputLayout is using. This code is only for changing text color for error. If you want to change other properties , you can add them to style.

Comment: If you want the error text color in current state you can use `getErrorCurrentTextColors`

Comment: Thanks. Really I don't want to change any color. I want to have error color to use it in another place.